# learned how to drive (a car)

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

A: You should learn to control your son.

B: Oh yeah? **And you should have learned how to drive ((a) car)**. Then you wouldn't be a bitter man clinging to a walker.

It certainly doesn't have many hits on Google, but would it be very unidiomatically to include "a car" or just "car" here?

Comment: We certainly would not leave out the article '**a**' and usually, "learn to drive" implicitly refers to a car, or it is obvious from the context. When said on a golf course, the context might inform that it's about the strokes you make.

Comment: Please tell us the source of the quote. It sounds like a move scene.

Comment: I wrote it myself.

Answer (score 1):

It would be probably more idiomatic to leave out 'a car' entirely. 'Learning to drive' implies a car, same as 'learning to fly' implies a plane, rather than flapping your arms ;)

You don't even need the 'how' in there. Just 'learned to drive' would be sufficient.

Your line is conversational, it's terse, it's combative. The fewer words, the more angry it sounds too.

> Oh yeah? And you should have learned to drive.